# php - convert 2012-06-25 19:00:00 to another format

Tags: php, time, strtotime, mktime

via xml, I am getting variables that give time in this format: 2012-06-25 19:00:00

I'd like it to be converted in this format: June 25 - 7:00PM

I have looked at mktime and strtotime, but im not sure how to handle a format that comes as a date AND time.

Comment: Look at [`date()`](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) or [DateTime](http://us.php.net/manual/en/book.datetime.php)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you said, you can use [strtotime](http://php.net/strtotime):

```
echo date('F-m - h:iA', strtotime($old_format));
```

Comment: I think he wants `echo date('F-m - h:iA', strtotime($old_format));`

Comment: @raym0nd Yep, you're right, thanks. Overlooked that.

Comment: thats it. Infact, I also want g instead of h. Thanks!

Comment: Doh, I thought i knew the whole format table in my head :)

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$input = "2012-06-25 19:00:00";

$dateTimeObject = new DateTime($input);
echo "First way: " . $dateTimeObject->format("F d - g:iA") . "<br>\n";

$date = date("F d - g:iA", strtotime($input));
echo "Second way: " . $date;
```